# Organising numbers from a text file into a 2 column matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

So I am trying to organise a .txt file in MATLAB. The file contains the width and height of some triangles (except for the first value, which is the number of triangles). The numbers are organised so that the 2nd value is the width and 3rd value is the height of triangle 1, 4th value is the width and 5th value is the height of triangle 2,and so on. The file starts off like this.

112

5

.2

1 3

1 2 3 5

54 8

81.4724   16.2182

..........................

So my question is. How do i get MATLAB to read this file, only starting from the second value, and then organise it into a (in this case 112 x2) matrix ? Also, do i need to specify how it organises the data ? as i need it to fill row one then row two etc.

So far I have

```
TriagnleArea = struct(width, height, area)
area = 0.5*width*height
FileID = fopen('SampleText','r')
A = fscanf('SampleText',%f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it correct.  When you're using `fopen`, you need to specify the `FileID` that determines the access point of where you have opened the file.  You are specifying the filename, which is not correct.

Next, you can simply read all of the values into one single array, extract out the first element to get the number of triangles you want and then pull out the rest of the values.  After, use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to restructure the array into the 2D matrix you desire.

```
%// Open up file for reading
FileID = fopen('SampleText', 'r');

%// Read all values into a single array
A = fscanf(FileID, '%f');

%// Close the file
fclose(FileID);

%// Pull out total number of triangles
numTriangles = A(1);

%// Look at the rest of the points and reshape them
%// into a N x 2 array
values = reshape(A(2:end), 2, numTriangles).';
```

---

Here's an example given your text file.  Here, you've only specified 12 values, so there are only 6 triangles.  As such, I've made a text file that looks like this:

```
6

5 .2

1 3

1 2 

3 5

54 8

81.4724 16.2182
```

If we put the above into a file called `SampleText`, this is what I get for both the number of triangles and the respective widths and heights:

```
>> numTriangles

numTriangles =

     6

>> values

values =

    5.0000    0.2000
    1.0000    3.0000
    1.0000    2.0000
    3.0000    5.0000
   54.0000    8.0000
   81.4724   16.2182
```

You can then calculate the area of each triangle by using the product of the width and height divided by 2:

```
>> areas = values(:,1).*values(:,2)/2

areas =

    0.5000
    1.5000
    1.0000
    7.5000
  216.0000
  660.6678
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Really helpful. However, I am still getting a single column matrix. I am using values = reshape(A(2:end), 2, numTriangles);  And tbh, i dont really undertstand what this peice of code is doing. I know it reshapes a matrix to whatever size you want. But i thought you would want somthing along the lines of values = reshape(A, [2:end,2]); ( not even sure if this is valid syntax)  so you would end up with a numTriangles x 2  matrix ?

Comment: @HaM551 - Are you sure?  You also need to transpose the result because if you don't, you'll get a `2 x N` matrix.  Using `reshape` like that shouldn't give you a single column matrix ever.... you're doing something wrong.  I just reran the code on my end with the sample text that I put in my post and it works.

Comment: It seems to be working now. Not sure why. However, the matrix it returns has values which are no where near to the ones in the .txt file, like 0.0001 0.0002 and so on.

Comment: @HaM551 - Are you sure you are specifying the correct input text file?

Comment: I am pretty sure. However, when i run the scirpt, i get                           values =                                                                                                               
1.0e+05*                                                                                                   then my 2 column matrix. Could it be, because i have some small numbers and large numbers, MATLAB is rounding them ?

Comment: ahh.... that's MATLAB's display format.  Your numbers are so large that the numbers actually are 0.0001 * 10e+05 for example.  Change your display format to `format long g`, then display your matrix again.  Type in `format long g;` in the command window, then display your matrix.